# launching keyboard of languages other than english

Tags: cocoa

i have build a Mac OS X sample application which can open on screen keyboard using

NSWorkSpace methods which is in english keys only. But, when i set the localization to other

language to japanese(say) then what should i do to launch the on screen key board with keys

appearing in japanese language.

Answer (score 0):

The Keyboard Viewer input method uses the keyboard layout of the last selected keyboard input source. You can select a keyboard input source using `TISSelectInputSource()`.

Comment: Although you probably shouldn't change the user's input source. The real takeaway is that the way to test this is not to change the active language, but to change (as the user/tester) the active input source.